# Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server is not working with RewriteEngine mode by .htaccess for specific folder

Tags: ubuntu, configuration, apache-virtualhost

While I am working with Web API project with Slim, I was using `.htaccess` for API folder `/v1` under root web. My OS is Ubuntu 16.04, with `Apache/2.4.18`.  I wanted to apply the .htaccess only for the `/v1` folder. The `.htaccess` file looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

When I try to access file in the `/v1` folder I get `404` response.
For example if try to access

> http://localhost/project/v1/loadSomething

The response will be 404:

```
Not Found
The requested URL project/v1/loadSomething was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80
```

I have tried to edit  to make some change like this:

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
   AllowOverride All
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
</Directory>
```

But the response in this case is 500,

```
Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
```

The logs looks like

```
[Sat Aug 10 21:16:11.356667 2019] [core:alert] [pid 4699] [client 127.0.0.1:33852] /var/www/html/project/v1/.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
[Sat Aug 10 21:20:21.783996 2019] [core:alert] [pid 4700] [client 127.0.0.1:34374] /var/www/html/project/v1/.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
[Sat Aug 10 21:20:40.368584 2019] [core:alert] [pid 4701] [client 127.0.0.1:34376] /var/www/html/project/v1/.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Since Apache 2.4 directives `Order`, `Allow` and `Deny` are deprecated and were replaced by the new [`Require`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_authz_core.html#require) syntax.

   Replace

   ```
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
   ```

   with

   ```
   Require all granted
   ```

   in your config. See https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/upgrading.html
2. It seems [mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) is not enabled in your server. Enable the module with the `a2enmod` command (which creates a symbolic link `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/rewrite.load` pointing to `../mods-available/rewrite.load`), then restart the server:

   ```
   sudo a2enmod rewrite
   sudo service apache2 restart
   ```

   To list all enabled modules you can use the `a2query` command with the `-m` flag:

   ```
   a2query -m
   ```

Comment: Thank you! I was not aware of the deprecation of Order, Allow and Deny. Now its working perfectly @Freddy.